# How to set flash message on ajax success redirect

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

As far as I can tell I have correctly followed other answers for this question. However my implementation is not working for whatever reason.

I am making an ajax request and redirecting with `location.href` upon success, and trying to figure out how to set a flash message.

This is in my controller:

```
if payment_service.succeeded?
  flash.notice = 'Your subscription was set up successfully!'
  json = { success: true, redirect_path: root_path }
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: json, status: 200 }
end
```

And this is where the ajax call is made:

```
fetch('/subscriptions/confirm_payment', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  body: JSON.stringify({ payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id })
}).then(function(result) {
  result.json().then(function(json) {

  if (response.error) {
    displayError(result.error);
  } else if (response.success) {
    location.href = response.redirect_path;
  }
})
```

I would expect to see the flash notice displayed after redirecting to `redirect_path`. But no flash is displayed.

Comment: https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/how-to-add-a-flash-message-to-your-rails-page/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flash.keep()` method.

It will keep content of `flash` message for further actions.
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html#method-i-keep

```
if payment_service.succeeded?
 flash.keep(:notice) = 'Your subscription was set up successfully!'
 json = { success: true, redirect_path: root_path }
end
```